# Leaflet detect when clicking inside or outside of a polygon

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have added a GeoJSON polygon using:

```
var activeMunicipality = L.geoJson(municipalities, {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {
            color: "#000",
            weight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0
        };
    },
    filter: function (feature, layer) {                     
        if (feature.properties.CAT_B === filterMunicipality) return true
    }, interactive: false
}).addTo(map);
map.panInsideBounds(activeMunicipality.getBounds());
map.setMaxBounds(activeMunicipality.getBounds());
```

I then also bind and open a popup every time the map is clicked using:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    layerGroup.clearLayers();       
    var location = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(layerGroup);
    var popup = location.bindPopup('<strong>Latitude:</strong> ' + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(5) + '<br> <strong>Longitude:</strong> ' + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(5));
    popup.openPopup();      
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

I only want the popup to be created when clicking **inside** of the GeoJSON. When clicking outside of the polygon, I would trigger something like

```
alert("The selected location is outside of your municipality");
```

Comment: Any special reason you don't want to have `activeMunicipality` layer interactive?

Comment: Because my map has other ways to find the user's location other than clicking on the map. Such as searching for an address or their current location. So for example, the results of the geocoder will also need to check if the location is inside or outside of the activeMunicipality before creating the popup.

Comment: I'm asking why are you setting option `interactive: false` for `activeMunicipality` layer?

Comment: No special reason. The layer can be interactive if needed for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to set feature click event processing in `onEachFeature` option. If click is caught there, it does not propagate to the map. Layer `activeMunicipality` has to be interactive for that to work.

Then just add map click event processing, where you display alert.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var activeMunicipality = L.geoJson(municipalities, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
    layer.on('click', function(evt) {
      onMapClick(evt);
    });
  },
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: "#000",
      weight: 2,
      fillOpacity: 0
    };
  },
  filter: function (feature, layer) {                     
    if (feature.properties.CAT_B === filterMunicipality) return true
  }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('click', alert("The selected location is outside of your municipality"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well.  Could this onEachFeature solution also be used to detect if a geocoder result is inside of the activeMunicipality layer or not?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Anyway, that's a different question, so you should put it as a new question.